How to create the simplest Docker image of Ubuntu 22.04 from scratch on the Ubuntu 22.04 system

oky
I used docker pull ubuntu, but I would like to know how Docker's Ubuntu image was created.

Did you actually read what was on the front page of the Docker images?

What's in this image?
This image is built from official rootfs tarballs provided by
Canonical (see dist-* tags at
https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+oci/ubuntu-base).
How is the rootfs built?
The tarballs published by Canonical, referenced by dist-* tags in
https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+oci/ubuntu-base Git
repository, are built from scripts that live in the livecd-rootfs
project, especially live-build/auto/build. The builds are run on
Launchpad. For build history see livefs build pages of individual
releases on Launchpad:

Focal
Jammy
Lunar
Mantic


